# error in accessing tables from hive using apache drill

Tags: plugins, hive, apache-drill, query-engine

I am trying to read the data from my table abc which is in hive using Drill. For that i have created hive storage plugin with the configuration mentioned below

```
{
"type": "hive",
"enabled": true,
"configProps": {
"hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://<ip>:<port>",
"fs.default.name": "hdfs://<ip>:<port>/",
"hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false",
"hive.server2.enable.doAs": "true",
"hive.metastore.execute.setugi": "true"
 }
 }
```

with this i am able to see the databases in hive, but when i try to access any table in the particular database

```
select * from hive.db.abc;
```

it throws the following error

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION
>   ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 18: Object 'abc' not
>   found within 'hive.db' SQL Query null [Error Id:
>   b6c56276-6255-4b5b-a600-746dbc2f3d67 on centos2.example.com:31010]
>   (org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException) From line 1,
>   column 15 to line 1, column 18: Object 'abc' not found within
>   'hive.db' sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0():-2
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance():62
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance():45
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance():423
>   org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex():463
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException():800
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException():788
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.newValidationError():4703
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.resolveImpl():127
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.validateImpl():177
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate():84
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace():947
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery():928
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom():2972
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter$DrillValidator.validateFrom():267
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom():2957
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter$DrillValidator.validateFrom():267
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateSelect():3216
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SelectNamespace.validateImpl():60
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate():84
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace():947
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery():928
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect.validate():226
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression():903
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate():613
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter.validate():190
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.validateNode():630
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.validateAndConvert():202
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.getPlan():174
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan():146
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan():84
>   org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL():567
>   org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run():264
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1149
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():624
>   java.lang.Thread.run():748 Caused By
>   (org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException) Object 'abc'
>   not found within 'hive.db'
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0():-2
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance():62
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance():45
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance():423
>   org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex():463
>   org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex():572
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException():800
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException():788
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.newValidationError():4703
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.resolveImpl():127
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.validateImpl():177
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate():84
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace():947
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery():928
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom():2972
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter$DrillValidator.validateFrom():267
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom():2957
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter$DrillValidator.validateFrom():267
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateSelect():3216
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SelectNamespace.validateImpl():60
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate():84
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace():947
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery():928
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect.validate():226
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression():903
>   org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate():613
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter.validate():190
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.validateNode():630
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.validateAndConvert():202
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.getPlan():174
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan():146
>   org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan():84
>   org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL():567
>   org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run():264
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1149
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():624
>   java.lang.Thread.run():748

Comment: What is the result of *USE HIVE;* and *SHOW TABLES;* ?

Comment: What versions of Drill and Hive do you use?

Comment: Hello @vitalii I am using Hive 1.2.2
Apache drill 1.13.0

On using use hive; in webcosnole ,it shows hive selected and on using  show tables it shows error .

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the newer Hive version. For Drill 1.13 it is Hive 2.3.2 version? Starting from Drill-1.13 Drill leverages 2.3.2 version of Hive client [1].

Supporting of Hive 3.0 version is upcoming [2].

Also please follow the following guide with necessary Hive plugin configurations for your environment [3]. You could omit "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "hive.server2.enable.doAs" and "hive.metastore.execute.setugi" properties, since you have specified the default values [4]. Regarding "hive.metastore.uris" and "fs.default.name" you should specify the same values for them as in your hive-site.xml.

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin 
[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6604 
[3] https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/#hive-remote-metastore-configuration 
[4] https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/rel/release-2.3.2/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java#L824